# PHP: How to get the Content-Length from stream request for chunk download

Tags: php, http, stream

I'm attempting to download archives from an external site in chunks. However, I'm encountering an issue where the `Content-Length` header, which I'm trying to retrieve using `get_headers()`, is not present.

Has anyone else experienced this issue when saving chunked responses and trying to retrieve the Content-Length?

```php
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken\r\n"
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);

// I'm trying to get the Content-Length to limit the file download to files larger than 1GB.
// $file_headers = get_headers($sourceFile, 1, $context);
// if($file_headers["Content-Type"])

$sourceFileStream = fopen($sourceFile, 'rb', false, $context);
```

How can I retrieve the Content-Type or the size of the response stream?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to calculate the size of an file opened inside the code (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674651/fastest-way-to-calculate-the-size-of-an-file-opened-inside-the-code-php)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the response is sent with [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.1)

Therefore, there is no `Content-Length` header field ([RFC 7320](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2)):
*A sender MUST NOT send a Content-Length header field in any message that contains a Transfer-Encoding header field.*

But you're lucky – the RFC also provides an [algorithm to decode a chunked transfer and get its length.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-4.1.3)